# Frequent travel between Berlin and London - what benefits/perks can I get?

Tags: london, loyalty-programs, berlin

I'm currently living in London, but I'll be moving to Berlin early next year - and I'll definitely be staying for a fair while. I've still got friends and family in London and Manchester, so it's likely that I'll be doing a fair bit of travelling back and forth - most likely by flying.

My question is this: what kind of benefits or perks can I get out of doing a lot of air travel back and forth between the two, and how can I best use this to my advantage?

For example, should I give my loyalty to a particular airline in order to get rewards? I kind of prefer British Airways, but I'm open to suggestions. Is there anything else I should think of, or take into consideration? Is it even worth trying to do anything like this, or should I just go for the cheapest flights regardless of carrier?

Comment: Which loyalty program to choose, or whether it is worth choosing one in the first place, depends on a number of factors, including what fare classes you buy (flexible/expensive company-paid tickets or cheap deals you're booking for personal excursions?) and what your goals for the program are (Mileage redemption for trips? Upgrades? Fee waivers?). Can you [edit](http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/37282/edit) your post to include more details?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62322/would-a-non-business-traveler-ever-benefit-from-collecting-air-miles-as-compare. The short version is that any frequent flier benefits you get on such a short route are meaningless compared to the tactic of simply getting the cheapest ticket each time.

Answer (score 7):

London-Berlin is a very short trip, a return is 1162 miles, for example status Lufthansa starts at 35 k and there aren't a lot of useful perks at that level, perhaps more luggage. Redemption requires a real lot of miles:

> taxes, fees and charges are not included in the mileage information. On European flights these can be settled with 18,000 miles.

Look here [miles-and-more.com](http://www.miles-and-more.com/mediapool/pdf/20/media_785183620.pdf) for the redemption chart. Say, you want to fly in comfort to the USA? That'll be 105 000 points or 90 such trips.

I would forget perks and just go for whoever the cheapest flight you can find.

Comment: Remember that innereuropean trips are not calculated by distance, but by fixed mile values. So a cheap economy ticket could earn you as low as 125 miles for one segment, the most expensive business class ticket would get you 2000 miles per segment.