# Would a non-business traveler ever benefit from collecting air miles, as compared to simply buying the cheapest ticket available?

Tags: air-travel, loyalty-programs

Looking at various air miles programs around the world, it seems to me that they're only useful for business travelers, who basically get free flights out of their employer's pocket. However for a regular Joe, who pays out of pocket, all of the programs seem useless when comparing to the option of simply flying the cheapest flight at any given time. Even benefits such as business lounges are either useless (why would I use a lounge on a non-transfer flight?) or can be bought for a reasonable fee when needed.

There are also credit cards which give out cashback in the form of air miles, however their pay-out is usually lower than simply getting a fixed cashback in dollars.

So, is it ever useful for a person to care about air miles if they're paying for everything out of their own pocket?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47305/discussion-on-question-by-jonathanreez-would-a-non-business-traveler-ever-benefi).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To directly answer the title question, yes, non-business travelers can absolutely benefit from airline loyalty programs (i.e. earning points/miles as well as status.) Whether it's worth it for you in particular, though, will be **extremely** dependent on your particular situation and what options are available to you on the routes you normally fly, as well as whether you typically need to take luggage, etc.

Since specific examples were requested, I'll use myself as an example. I live in the Southeast U.S. and fly round-trips within the U.S. typically a few times per year and inter-continental round-trips about once a year. While there are sometimes slightly cheaper *advertised fares* to my domestic destinations on some of the very-low-cost airlines, by the time I add all of the fees and other associated costs of flying one of those airlines, they would often end up costing as much or more than Southwest or Delta. This is especially true due to the fact that the very-low-cost airlines usually have infrequent flight schedules that are much more likely to require me to take an extra day off of work than with an airline like SWA or DL where flights leave about every hour. So, in the end, Southwest or Delta usually ends up being the lowest *actual* cost to me and both earn points/miles on every flight that don't expire (Delta miles don't expire at all and Southwest points remain active as long as you have at least some account activity once every two years.)

As far as redemption value, this again varies widely and will depend very largely on your use case. For me, these two programs are my primary options due to where I live:

### Southwest

In the case of Southwest, you typically earn 6 points per dollar spent on the cheap fares and can redeem points at a rate of 70 points per dollar of airfare. If you purchase the ticket with a Southwest co-branded credit card, you earn 8 points per dollar instead of 6. So, without their card, you get a dollar worth of airfare for every $11.67 spent on airfare and, with their card, you get a dollar of airfare for every $8.75 spent.

### Delta

Delta's scheme is much more complicated and can range from much more valuable to much less valuable depending on your situation. For my situation, it's more valuable.

#### Earning miles

With Delta, you earn 5 points per dollar of airfare as the base rate. If you buy the ticket with a Delta co-branded credit card, that goes up to 7 points per dollar. If you additionally have status with Delta, you get an additional 2, 3, 4, or 6 points per dollar based on your level of status. In my case, I get 10 points per dollar total at my current status level (which came entirely from personal travel, not business travel.) Note that there is no bonus or penalty to this for different fare or cabin classes, but you inherently earn more points on more expensive fares since it's based on dollars spent. So, if I buy a $200 round-trip fare, I earn 2,000 'miles' regardless of fare class, distance actually traveled, etc.

#### Redeeming miles

While miles are earned on a dollar-cost basis, mileage redemption with Delta is (loosely) based on an award chart, with mileage cost depending on region traveled to/from and demand for that particular route (i.e. usually only a few seats are available at the lowest mileage costs on a given flight.) If you book early, domestic round trips usually start at 25,000 miles (sometimes 20,000, but this is less common.) If you book a $200 round trip for 25,000 miles, that's obviously not a great value (less than 0.8 cents/mile value.) However, the 'regions' are quite large, with the entire U.S. and Canada (excluding Hawaii) being a single 'region.' So, if you book a $500 trans-continental round-trip for 25,000 miles, that's obviously a *much* better value (2 cents/mile, which is equivalent to $1 of airfare earned for every $5 of airfare purchased at my earning rate of 10 miles/dollar.)

The best redemption values I've seen on Delta are for long-haul business class flights with 140,000 miles getting you a business class ticket to the other side of the planet that would normally cost $7k if bought with cash, a 5 cent/mile value. So, if I'm earning 10 points per dollar of airfare and redeeming for 5 cents/mile of value, **that's 50 cents per dollar originally spent** (i.e. $1 of airfare earned for every $2 of airfare purchased!) In my case, this is exactly how I prefer to use the points, as I'm not really a fan of flying economy (and, thus, getting no sleep) on routes that involve 30-36 hours of travel time (20-22 of that actually airborne) each direction.

### Conclusion for a non-business traveler

If you only ever travel short distances, always buy the cheapest tickets, and don't earn miles separately from credit cards, then you're probably never going to get up to 140,000 miles. However, 25,000 miles is certainly very attainable for the non-business traveler, since the points don't expire ($2,500 of total airfare purchased at my earning rate.) An extra $500 of free airfare for every $2,500 spent isn't a bad deal at all, even if it takes you a few years to buy that much airfare.

An additional aid to those who don't fly as often is that, with both Delta and Southwest, there's no penalty for booking just one way with points vs. booking a round-trip with points. So, using the trans-continental Delta flight example, you could get one way for 12,500 points and just pay cash for the other way and be able to get your first redemption after spending only $1,250 while getting the same value per dollar spent.

So, yes, there are definitely cases where it's useful for a non-business traveler to care about points. However, whether that's the case for you or not will be highly dependent on the flight options available where you live, the relative cost of those options, where and how often you tend to fly, and what the terms are of the frequent flier programs of the airline choices you have available. As you can see from just the two examples I've listed, the terms for different frequent flier programs and their relative usefulness to you can vary significantly from one airline to another (and that's before even considering elite status.)

Comment: +1 Nice answer with examples. You give a nice glimpse into just how complicated it can all be without being vague and saying it's "nearly impossible to answer". It's not, you just did.

Comment: Great answer with examples! Thank you! I was indeed wrong about my assumptions.

Comment: one correction: Delta miles *do* expire. I had nearly 600000 miles collected, and they mailed me a week after they expired to let me know that they are now lost. (Thanks, Delta. I cannot really expect you get the idea of telling me *before*)

Comment: @Aganju Delta miles *used to* expire with two years of inactivity on the account. This was changed a few years ago. See "Account Deletion & Mileage Expiration" under "SkyMiles Rules & Conditions" on http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/skymiles/program-rules-conditions.html for the new policy. Mind you, they can always change their policy on a whim, but for now they do not expire.

Comment: QANTAS at least, the price of buying a flight tomorrow with frequent flyer points is the same as buying one 6 months out. If you need a flight in a hurry for some emergency reason (and there is still one available), you can dramatically increase the $ conversion rate of your points.

Comment: @Aganju lc is correct. Prior to the merger with Northwest, Delta miles expired after two years of account inactivity. However, the Northwest WorldPerks miles didn't expire at least as far back as the 90s and a lot of people complained when they were told that the miles they accumulated with Northwest would suddenly be subject to expiration 2 years after the Delta merger. As a result, Delta walked back on that policy and made Delta miles never expire.

Comment: Looks like Delta only gives out 2 miles/dollar for their credit card as of 2019. Any advice on the best way to earn miles at the moment?

Comment: @JonathanReez It's 5 base miles that you earn from Delta, plus 2 for purchasing with their CC, for a total of 7 miles/dollar (plus whatever you may get from status.) That said, there are actually better credit card options out there now. The Amex Platinum Card (the regular one, not the Delta co-branded one) earns 5 points/dollar on any airfare purchase and the points can be transferred to any of 19 different airline loyalty programs, including Delta. Citi Prestige (5x) and Chase Sapphire Reserve (3x) are also good options.

Comment: @JonathanReez Having said that, the redemption side with Delta definitely isn't what it was when I wrote this answer today. They've switched to dynamic award pricing rather than a set award chart, so the 7 cent/point type values that I mentioned in the answer are much harder to find nowadays. 2-3 cents/point is more realistic for a good Delta redemption now, though sometimes you may get a bit more. And many redemption options are in the more pathetic ~1 cent/mile range. Fortunately, getting transferable points from Amex, Chase, etc. helps to work around this by booking through partners.

Answer (score 29):

There are three things that set (some) frequent flier programs apart from other rewards programs. How important these are to you may determine whether they are worth doing.

The first is "Status" which you refer to by mentioning business travellers. Never lining up, spending an hour or more **less** in the airport than others, waiting in the lounge eating and using free internet, and getting upgraded for free are all pretty cool. But unless you fly an average of a thousand miles a week, (50,000 a year) you aren't getting these and can ignore them.

The second is that miles awarded don't always correlate with money spent, enabling silly things like "mileage runs". This makes it impossible to say that your program gives you 1% or 2% or 0.5%. A person who makes long direct flights between popular airports will get a higher percentage back than people who make connecting flights involving less popular airports, because they're spending more money but getting the same miles for it.

The third, and the only one that applies to me, is that redemptions don't always correlate with price. (I'm not talking about those travel-only credit card reward things that go on about any airline any time no blackouts - those are just a dollars-for-points redemption. If the price doubles, the points you need double.) Airlines still exist with redemptions where the points come from a chart. This means, for example, that Toronto-Vancouver-Nanaimo costs the same points as Toronto-Vancouver, even though a paid-for-ticket might cost almost double to add on that little local leg. It's also pretty common for business class to cost only 25% more points even though it might cost 5 **times** the dollars. This let me do Toronto-London-Venice-Toronto, all business, for barely more than Toronto-London-Toronto in economy, and treat my mother to a number of business class flights and three days in Venice.

I used to chase status, but the programs changed a lot and I no longer find it worthwhile. I choose the flight that's best for me, whether I'm paying for it or my client is. Because of where I live, it's often on the airline I collect points from, and I collect them when I fly that airline. I look carefully for redemptions that save me more than a penny for each mile I spend - two is even better - and use those when I can. As I mentioned above, tickets that would cost the same dollars don't always cost the same points, so I never assume that a redemption is a good deal. On my own recent epic trip, I flew on the airline that I collect on, but for several legs I paid $50 less not to get the miles. I did the math and they weren't worth $50 to me.

My advice? Sign up for frequent flyer programs, but don't let them drive your decisions. As the points pile up, look at how to use them, but keep a spreadsheet handy. Little actions like using one chain of gas stations because they give you miles, or one drugstore because it gives you miles, are harmless enough if you like that chain anyway, but don't go out of your way to accumulate miles you may never use. And never pay extra for a flight that earns miles, whether that's a charge on your airline or the price difference between two airlines. Keep them mentally filed as a bonus gift some folks give you, not as a motivator that you chase, and pay for with time and money. You'll be happier and have more money, too.

Answer (score 13):

tldr: If you travel once or twice a year, on full-price airlines with frequent flyer progammes, sign up for them. But don't obsess over them, and focus on price and other benefits first.

---

Longer answer:

As always, it depends.

Many (most?) budget airlines don't have a frequent flyer programme (or at least one comparable to those on full-service airlines), so if you mostly fly on those, it will take a long time to acquire enough miles to do anything useful. Some airlines (ahem, Lufthansa) also have a nasty habit of "expiring" old miles, even if you are still actively flying with them from time to time, so definitely avoid those if you don't travel (and redeem) often.

It is true that if you are only flying for leisure, miles will probably trickle in slowly, whether you plan to fly budget airlines or not. As such, you probably won't get much/any elite status levels, and the benefits won't really be relevant.

Incidentally, I think you are wrong about some of the benefits - lounges are very useful even when not on a transfer (most of my flights don't involve a transfer, but I still use the lounge before virtually every departure, since getting through security with no time to waste but never missing a flight, consistently, is virtually impossible), and they *do* cost a lot - in fact for some airports (e.g. Heathrow T5 until recently) didn't have the option to pay for them at all.

Answer (score 6):

It all depends on how frequently you travel and what type of travels. If you just perform 2 domestic flights every 2 years, then miles collection isn't worth... If you take more than few flights every year including some long distance flights, then it is worth, even in economy class, even with the cheapest ticket.

To give you some figures, with some airlines, 2 round trips from USA to Europe (so 4 flights) would allow you to collect enough miles for a domestic flight.

Then, miles collection doesn't cost anything as long as you take the cheapest ticket so there is no reason to avoid it... But again, this is really dependent on how frequently you travel. If it is once every 2 years, not worth as your miles will likely expire before your next flight.

Comment: "2 round trips from USA to Europe would allow you to collect enough miles for a domestic flight" - could you provide a full calculation? Usually the catch is that most of the ticket is 'taxes' not covered by miles, so the savings are minimal.

Comment: This is a generic calculation I made. One round trip would allow you to gather between 4.000 and 7.000 miles depending on the trip and ticket. Then with around 10.000 miles, you can buy a domestic flight on some airlines.

Comment: It sounds right *in theory*, but could you provide an example with specific flights and dates?

Comment: Check out there : https://www.flyingblue.com/promo-awards.html

Comment: I'm also skeptical. Specifically because the miles that need to be spend are typically related to the regular price of the ticket you want to buy, while I don't think there are situations where taxes are included in the part of the ticket you can get by using airmiles. In addition, it requires you to always fly with the same airline, or at least with the same alliance, which might not be relevant at all, if you're trying to get the cheapest ticket on *every* flight. So, as a recreational traveler, you'd need to fly a lot to make this worth your while.

Comment: @MastaBaba the calculation has become way more complex these days and it is hard to give a rule that would cover all the situations. The more you fly, the more you get, especially if you are staying with the same airline and paying more expensive fares. BUT even with few flights per year, you can still accrue enough miles for a domestic flights on some airlines (not all, but some).

Comment: @Olielo well, that's the catch... you usually have to buy a more expensive fare to get the miles, which completely negates one's savings

Comment: @JonathanReez You get a miles incentive for buying more expensive tickets BUT it isn't always mandatory to earn miles. Cheaper tickets are usually also entitled for miles. Having said that, you should just see the miles as an incentive to fly with the same alliance, nothing more. Some people tend to fly for miles to accrue more and more miles but this is a non sense as ultimately, they just spend money to get another type of money... Hotel reward programs are also much more generous on that front.

Comment: @Olielo my calculations show that the incentive is actually a lie, as no one ever saves any money by choosing a more expensive 'alliance' ticket over what's cheapest. However I'm not a super-savvy traveler, so I might be wrong.

Comment: @JonathanReez This is an incentive, not a free gift. Based on my calculations, you get back less than 5% of what you have paid. So if you have spent 10.000$, then you can buy a ticket worth less than 500$. But again, it varies based on the ticket class, the fare, etc...

Comment: This comment thread shows exactly the uncertainty displayed by @JonathanReez in the original question. Sure, there are scenarios where collected air miles *could* get a non-business traveler a ticket, but if we presume this traveler in principle will get the cheapest ticket between two places, does that still hold?

Comment: Once again: Can you specify which 'some airlines' you are talking about? To give a specific example of the opposite: Lufthansa credits you with about 1,900 miles for the cheapest transatlantic roundtrip fare and charges you at least 33,000 miles for a free domestic flight within Germany (taxes inclusive).

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo He's probably talking about the U.S. airlines. With Delta, for example, if you buy a $1,000 round-trip trans-Atlantic fare, you'd get 5,000 points. If you have their co-branded card, that goes up to 7,000. If you have low-tier status with them (I do and nearly all of my travel is non-business,) that goes up to 9,000 or 10,000. Domestic (U.S.) round-trips start at 20,000-25,000 points, so 2-3 trans-Atlantic round-trips can definitely get you there. Also, their points never expire, so you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: @MastaBaba `but if we presume this traveler in principle will get the cheapest ticket between two places, does that still hold?` Sure it holds that it _sometimes_ can get you a ticket. At least where I live (Southeast U.S.) the cheapest options often are with airlines that have loyalty programs and, with some of those programs, the points never expire. It's very dependent on your particular situation, though.

Comment: @reirab Yeah, I figured. Yet, still, would that ticket be based on the regular fare of the ticket, or on a discounted fare that you would otherwise be able to get? Either way, an actual example as in the first comment in this thread would be helpful.

Comment: @MastaBaba Rather than answering in the comments, I just wrote [an answer that addresses this](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/62345/12011).

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately that is difficult to answer: About two years ago a large part of the industry (United, Delta) shifted the accrual from "miles flown" to "dollars spend" with a very complex set of rules. These programs are now pretty much useless for the occasional flyer.

Other ways to earn miles are associated credit cards. These offer miles for dollars spend and still have a pretty good accrual rate.

Typically a domestic round trip saver ticket costs 25.000 miles (United, American, etc). That used to be three round trips to Europe or two round trips to China or less if you have premier status with the airline. Today this calculation is a lot more difficult and depends on the individual rules of each airline.

Comment: I think your answer is quite US-specific. Most airlines outside the US still have programs that reward based on mileage, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier While most non-U.S. airline loyalty programs are _sort of_ based on mileage, many of them apply multipliers based on the particular fare class, leading to a similar effect.

Comment: @reirab agreed, fair point.

Answer (score 3):

> There are also credit cards which give out cashback in the form of air miles, however their pay-out is usually lower than simply getting a fixed cashback in dollars.

Aeroplan points exchanged for international business tickets can be worth 4.5-6CPM and if you manage to find an upgradeable ticket it can be 10-12CPM. I've never seen a generic cashback above 2% , some special card+store combinations perhaps 4% but even that's rare. By churning and using Aeroplan cards I collect enough points to fly to Europe twice a year in comfort.

Comment: So, what's the total rate of conversion of credit card purchases to air tickets?

Comment: As I tried to say: depends on what kind of air ticket you buy. As an example, Vancouver-Vienna return in business is 5762.57 CAD, vs 110 000 miles + 936.71 CAD, so your 110 000 miles is equivalent to 4825 which means one mile in this case is 4.3 cents. With a bit of trickery with routing, you can save most of the taxes (search on United for flights not with Air Canada nor Lufthansa, then call Aeroplan), so you will be getting ~5600 dollars out of your 110 000 miles, making a mile 5 cents. If you go to Australia/Asia, it's an even better deal. And so on...

Comment: Could you also add a calculation for the scenario where one doesn't buy business class tickets? That would make it more balanced.

Comment: It's not worth it in that case. The very point of this is making flying on business class affordable.

Answer (score 2):

My strategy as a non business traveler is to have a few accounts with airlines that I know I will want to redeem miles with and that have a good airline alliance/code share program.

For example, I have a mileage account with American. I fly quite a bit with American as well as US Airlines and Alaska. Then I use the miles collected with these airlines towards reward travel with American.

I think you should evaluate all airlines for each major alliance (Sky Team, One World, Star Alliance) and create a mileage account for one airline in each of the three. It only makes sense to have one account per alliance since you cannot consolidate the miles (maybe possible but at a cost).

Additionally, there are a few airlines that do not participate in any alliance (like Iceland Air, for example). You should only join those mileage programs if you intend to travel with those airlines more than once a year since otherwise your miles will expire anyways.