# How can I quickly know how much mileage a flight ticket will earn?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, loyalty-programs

Is there some convenient online resource that could tell me how much mileage a given flight ticket will earn, for a given loyalty program? E.g., input = (flight number=UA 2630, fare class=K, fare=100 USD, loyalty program=MileagePlus), output = 500 miles earned for the MileagePlus program. It's tedious to have do the math oneself, so I wonder if there exist some time-efficient online calculator. I understand the input may have more parameters.

I found:

- https://www.mapdevelopers.com/mileage_calculator.php is useful to compute flight distances
- https://www.wheretocredit.com/ is useful to view eligible fare classes
- some loyalty program websites e.g. [MileagePlus](https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/mileageplus/earn-miles/airline-partners.html) mention mileage equations given the operating airline, ticketing airline, fare class, fare, distance, etc.

but I would prefer a more fully automated system.

Comment: I very much doubt this exists.  It's hard enough to find this information for one airline, never mind all of them.

Comment: For your example is all depends on the $$ you paid for the ticket and your status. $$ is related to fare class, but it's not the same. Distance only enters the equation if you are flying on a non-United ticket. Detailed rules are https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/mileageplus/earn-miles/united.html . I doubt that any one would voluntarily code this up.

Comment: Southwest tells you upfront as you pick flights (and fare group) on their website.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62322/would-a-non-business-traveler-ever-benefit-from-collecting-air-miles-as-compare

Comment: Many airlines now tell you when you book (most probably when they give you the choice between multiple fares and show a comparison table), though of course this is far from universal, and usually applies only if you use the airline’s own program.

Answer (score -2):

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/awardtravel/comments/11c2crl/how_can_i_quickly_know_how_much_mileage_a_flight/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=android_app&utm_name=androidcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) pointed me to these two resources:

- Android application (paid): http://www.milecalc.com/ ; [Application on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.milecalc.app&hl=en_US&gl=US).
- Calculator for United MileagePlus: https://pqp.economiles.com/

Comment: The 2nd of these is using calculations that haven't been correct for close to 10 years. The 1st link doesn't work so I can't comment on that one...

Comment: @Doc https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.milecalc.app&hl=en_US&gl=US